# DataInputStream readUTF gives incorrect string-value

Tags: java, datainputstream, dataoutputstream

I´m a beginner at writing code that communicates with a server so I´m starting with something simple: To send a string to a server and then read it.

The full code is as follows (with censored IP-address and port):

```
public class ServerCommunication implements Runnable {
//components to connect to server
private Socket socket;
private InputStream inputStream;
private DataInputStream dataInputStream;
private OutputStream outputStream;
private DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;

private static final String TAG = "ServerCommunication"; //for Log.d messages
private int seconds;


public ServerCommunication(int seconds) {
    this.seconds = seconds;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    for(int i = 0; i < seconds; i++) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "startThread: " + i);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    connectToServer();
    writeSimpleMessageToServer();
    readSimpleMessageFromServer();
}

public void connectToServer() {
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, ".....TRYING_TO_CONNECT.....");
        socket = new Socket("xx.xxx.x.xxx", xxxx); //address, port
        inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
        outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);
        Log.d(TAG, "SERVER_CONNECTED_!");

    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void writeSimpleMessageToServer() {
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "...WRITING_TO_SERVER...");

        String message = "yourName";
        dataOutputStream.writeUTF(message);

        dataOutputStream.flush();

    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "WRITING_DONE");
}

public void readSimpleMessageFromServer() {
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "...READING_FROM_SERVER...");
        Log.d(TAG, "SERVER_MEDDELANDE: " + dataInputStream.readUTF());

    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "READING_DONE");
} }
```

When I run the code the readUTF doesn´t return the correct value `yourName` but instead returns the string `{"type":"exception","message":"Unexpected char=y"}`. I´ve no idea why this happens.

I´ve tried looking into some other questions regarding the same/similar issue here on stackoverflow and many pointed out that if you use `writeUTF` the corresponding `readUTF` has to be used - but I´m already doing this so that can´t be the problem. I came across someone talking about that writeUTF does not only write the string but also writes how many bytes the string is, and that you need to read this first before you try to read the actual string. I failed to find any examples of how this works so I don´t know how I would do that or if it would actually help solve my problem.

Comment: That looks like JSON to me - if your server a REST endpoint? Can you explain what your server is?

Comment: If **you** use `readUTF`, the other side has to use `writeUTF` (and vice-versa). The other side is not using `writeUTF`. You should not be using `readUTF` (or `writeUTF`).

Comment: Could you clarify what it is that looks like JSON? The server is written by a teacher at college (code we don´t have access to) so all I know is the code I have to connect to it, unfortunately.

Comment: `{"type":"exception","message":"Unexpected char=y"}` is [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). Seems like the server you try to access isn't expecting the character `y` (the first character of your message and is sending you this as an answer so you know that something unexpected happened (the server expected something else from you). But without the server code or a description of the server we probably can't help you.